# Select results and order by in list items

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to display the result of my MySQL query by ordering them as they are listed in the where clause. Currently, the results are not listed in the order of the numbers in my list.

Here is my statement

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription
WHERE phone in 
(
    '255769016082',
    '255742594724',
    '255753299742',
    '255759502732',
    '255753839708'
)
```

Comment: So? Where is the order by statement in your select? How you want to order them? Add some info please.

Comment: Hi Maxim, i didnt put the order, as i dont know the correct statement for my query. How ever i tried Order by (Column_Name) Desc or Asc, and it was execute successfully. But my concern is to arrange the result in the order i list in sql statement.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to order by multiple values in a non-sequential order, that is they aren't numerically in order nor would they be ordered correctly in order as a VARCHAR, you need to apply numeric values to them. Here is how you can do that.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp

create table #temp (phone varchar(20))

insert into #temp (phone) values
('255769016082'),
('255742594724'),
('255753299742'),
('255759502732'),
('255753839708'),
('257538312333')

SELECT * 
FROM #temp
WHERE phone in 
(
    '255769016082',
    '255742594724',
    '255753299742',
    '255759502732',
    '255753839708'
)
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN phone = '255769016082' THEN 1
    WHEN phone = '255742594724' THEN 2
    WHEN phone = '255753299742' THEN 3
    WHEN phone = '255759502732' THEN 4
    WHEN phone = '255753839708' THEN 5
END
```

In the future, if you are sorting on non-numeric fields, you need to be familiar how SQL Server handles this.

Consider this

```
if object_id('tempdb..#char') is not null drop table #char

create table #char(stringField varchar(6))

insert into #char (stringField) values
('a'),
('A'),
('b'),
('B'),
('AB'),
('aB'),
('ab'),
('Ab'),
('ba'),
('Ba'),
('bA'),
('BA')

select * from #char order by stringField asc
select * from #char order by stringField desc
```